# Elixir: How to filter a Map by keys

Tags: elixir

I have a Map with key-value pairs and a Tuple with atoms. I want to remove any entry from the Map where the key is not an atom in the Tuple

```
m = %{value1: nil, value2: nil, value4: nil}
t = {:value1, :value3, :value4}
# The result should be %{value1: nil, value4: nil}
```

It is kind of an intersect problem. I looked into `Enum.filter` and `MapSet` but didn't find an elegant solution. This must be a common problem and your input is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think the key whitelist should be a list in the first place, not a tuple.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use [`Map.take/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#take/2) and a [`Tuple.to_list/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Tuple.html#to_list/1):

```
iex(1)> m = %{value1: nil, value2: nil, value4: nil}
%{value1: nil, value2: nil, value4: nil}
iex(2)> t = {:value1, :value3, :value4}
{:value1, :value3, :value4}
iex(3)> Map.take(m, Tuple.to_list(t))
%{value1: nil, value4: nil}
```

Comment: Do you know if the opposite of `take` also exists? A function that would "blacklist" certain keys?

Comment: @peedee yes, check out `Map.drop/2`.